# Extra height in inline-block

Tags: html, css, display

Q. How do I remove the extra space at the bottom of the `div#inlineblock`? Why is it there?

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f3f6db;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

hr {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: width .2s linear;
}

div#inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="block"><span>Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div id="inlineblock"><span>Inline Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate good references. :P

Thanks.

Comment: @Hitmands Okay. how do I go about removing it?

Comment: `inline-block` shouldn't be used while layouting. Use `flex-boxes` instead... (btw, if you wanna keep going with that, just reset `line-height`)

Comment: @Hitmands how do i reset it? `line-height: normal;`?

Comment: others already solved your issue. Fix it in those ways or use the right tools to achieve that.

Comment: @Hitmands The issue is solved. But your way is different and there is no harm in learning. what tools precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's happening here is that your `<hr />` has a margin (as is normal for `<hr />` elements) and it's being treated differently.

In the case of `#block`, it's being subject to [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) but in `#inlineblock` it isn't.

You can resolve this by specifying `margin-bottom:0` on your `hr` elements.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f3f6db;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

hr {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: width .2s linear;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* NEW */
}

div#inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="block"><span>Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div id="inlineblock"><span>Inline Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You'll notice this now pushed the two elements together, so you may need to add a `margin-bottom` to your `div`s depending on the exact effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

The space at the bottom of `#inlineblock` is actually the margin of the `hr`.  If you reset that margin, you'll see the 'space' disappear.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f3f6db;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

hr {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: width .2s linear;
}

div#inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
#inlineblock hr {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="block"><span>Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div id="inlineblock"><span>Inline Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> margin-bottom(and top) default for `hr` element is `8px`, you must set it to `0px`.

```
#inlineblock hr {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f3f6db;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

hr {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: width .2s linear;
}

#inlineblock hr {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

div#inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="block"><span>Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div id="inlineblock"><span>Inline Block</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the following:

```
div#inlineblock {
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Idk what you're trying to do but it didn't work for me. :(